# jQuery .clone with datalist

Tags: jquery, function, cross-browser

I have a html with an `<input>` element that has a "list" attribute pointing to an existing `<datalist>` in this html.
When I .clone the input element, in Chrome (88.0) and Edge, the list is still available in the cloned element. In Firefox (82.0), the list is lost.

```html
      var $clone = $('#stations_avail');
      var globaldatalist = $clone.prop('list');
      $clone = $clone.clone(false).removeAttr('id');
      $clone.change(function() {
        var locallist = this.list; // null in Firefox; okay in Chrome
      });
```

I have tried to .clone(true, true) with no change to the outcome.
I have tried to re-set the list attribute/prop after cloning but that does not work either.

The browser still keeps the connection to the datalist in the cloned element; it shows all the options.

I have a workaround with the globaldatalist from before the declaration of .change(), but I would prefer it when the object contains its datalist as it does in Chrome and Edge.